# JBoss Configuration in RHEL 7.4 for missing data source

Tags: sql-server, database, jboss, jboss-eap-7

I am trying to deploy a .war file called LicenseManager.war. The data server is hosted on another machine with an ip address. I am the database drivers have been correctly imported. After trying to copy and paste the LicenseManager.war file in deployments folder, the deployment fails and a LicenseManager.war.failed is created. The following is the server log :

```
2017-09-07 14:38:47,802 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
2017-09-07 14:38:47,825 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
2017-09-07 14:38:47,859 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
2017-09-07 14:38:47,859 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
2017-09-07 14:38:48,415 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYWELD0006: Starting Services for CDI deployment: LicenseManager.war
2017-09-07 14:38:48,602 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-1) WELD-000900: 2.3.3 (redhat)
2017-09-07 14:38:48,851 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYWELD0009: Starting weld service for deployment LicenseManager.war
2017-09-07 14:38:49,303 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
2017-09-07 14:38:49,642 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "LicenseManager.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
    "jboss.persistenceunit.\"LicenseManager.war#LicenseManager\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.manageIDDatasource]",
    "jboss.persistenceunit.\"LicenseManager.war#LicenseManager\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.manageIDDatasource]"
]}
2017-09-07 14:38:49,734 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "LicenseManager.war" (runtime-name : "LicenseManager.war")
2017-09-07 14:38:49,755 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.manageIDDatasource (missing) dependents: [service jboss.persistenceunit."LicenseManager.war#LicenseManager", service jboss.persistenceunit."LicenseManager.war#LicenseManager".__FIRST_PHASE__] 

2017-09-07 14:38:50,197 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990/management
2017-09-07 14:38:50,198 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990
2017-09-07 14:38:50,198 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: JBoss EAP 7.0.0.GA (WildFly Core 2.1.2.Final-redhat-1) started (with errors) in 18730ms - Started 578 of 983 services (135 services failed or missing dependencies, 385 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
2017-09-07 14:38:50,410 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped client-mappings cache from ejb container
2017-09-07 14:38:50,541 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment LicenseManager.war (runtime-name: LicenseManager.war) in 301ms
2017-09-07 14:38:50,724 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDR0002: Content removed from location /home/aboshi/EAP-7.0.0/standalone/data/content/7e/7e872f95551f1c9ff56e422fcc5a18b44a4e12/content
2017-09-07 14:38:50,724 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0009: Undeployed "LicenseManager.war" (runtime-name: "LicenseManager.war")
2017-09-07 14:38:50,783 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."LicenseManager.war".WeldBootstrapService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."LicenseManager.war".component."com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.CommandButtonTag".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."LicenseManager.war".component."com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.RegexValidatorTag".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."LicenseManager.war".component."com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.SelectItemTag".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."LicenseManager.war".component.LicenseTimerBean.WeldInterceptorBindingsService, WFLYCTL0208: ... and 63 more ] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."LicenseManager.war".WeldStartService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."LicenseManager.war".component."com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.CommandButtonTag".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."LicenseManager.war".component."com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.RegexValidatorTag".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."LicenseManager.war".component."com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.SelectItemTag".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."LicenseManager.war".component.LicenseTimerBean.WeldInterceptorBindingsService, WFLYCTL0208: ... and 64 more ] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."LicenseManager.war".beanmanager (missing) dependents: [service jboss.persistenceunit."LicenseManager.war#LicenseManager"] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."LicenseManager.war".component.LicenseManagerAction.CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."LicenseManager.war".component.LicenseManagerAction.START] service jboss.deployment.unit."LicenseManager.war".component.LicenseManagerAction.JndiBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."LicenseManager.war".jndiDependencyService] 
service
```

Also, one of the main errors is :

```
6:34:19,720 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "LicenseManager.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
    "jboss.persistenceunit.\"LicenseManager.war#LicenseManager\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.manageIDDatasource]",
    "jboss.persistenceunit.\"LicenseManager.war#LicenseManager\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.manageIDDatasource]"
]}
```

This is way too much to understand. Also, a similar configuration ran successfully on a windows 7 OS where again, the database was external. But this one is on RHEL 7.4. Can some please help me understand what is going on? Thank you very much!!

Regards,
Abhi Joe

Comment: It looks like you're maybe missing the data source configuration. What version of JBoss EAP or WildFly are you using?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I am using the version 7.0.0. I did import the SQL drivers by copyign and pasting them inside the modules->systems->layers->base->com-> location. I also cjhecked the configuration of moduel.xml. Thank you!!

Comment: How did you define them in JBoss EAP though?

Comment: <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/manageIDDataSource" pool-name="linuxenv1" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://10.77.6.20;databaseName=MUCS_0125</connection-url>
                    <driver>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver>
                    <new-connection-sql>select 1</new-connection-sql>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>5000</max-pool-size>
                    </pool>

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins<driver name="com.sql" module="com.sql">
                        <xa-datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SqlServerDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>

Comment: <driver name="com.sql" module="com.sql">
                        <xa-datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SqlServerDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>

Comment: The full log will be useful here. It looks like the data source is not being found. Your persistence.xml may also be useful.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins are there any kown support issues of Jboss EAP 7.0.0 with JSF? The .war file contains JSF based code. Thank you very much for your help!! Appreciate it!!

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Persistence.xml is  <properties>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect" />
   <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
   <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
   <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
   <property name="hibernate.listeners.envers.autoRegister" value="false" />
   <property name="cache.use_minimal_puts" value="true" />
  </properties>

Comment: JBoss EAP 7 is a Java EE 7 certified container. It should have no issues with JSF.

Comment: I had to delete the commented Oracle data source definition in persistence.xml and it was successfully deployed. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems JBoss is not finding the datasource where it expects it:
jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.manageIDDatasource

You might first turn logging to 'debug' then start the server-- grep for any lines that deal with manageIDDatasource.

It's quite possible the deployment of the datasource wasn't as smooth as could be.  Look for examples of doing this, then when there are no errors things should be better.  (If there are still questions about the validity of the datasource, then maybe write a small servlet to retrieve and test it)

Comment: I had to delete the commented Oracle data source definition in persistence.xml and it was successfully deployed. Thank you!!